# httpChannel.redirectTo() infinite load

Tags: javascript, firefox, redirect, firefox-addon

I'm working on a firefox extension for the first time, and thanks to the documentation, it's going on pretty fast.
I've a problem however : I wan't to redirect the users if they go on some domains.

```
const {Cc, Ci, Cr, Cu} = require("chrome");
const buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");



var httpRequestObserver =
{
  observe: function(subject, topic, data)
  {
    if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
    var httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
    var eTLDService = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/effective-tld-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIEffectiveTLDService);
    var suffix = eTLDService.getPublicSuffixFromHost(httpChannel.originalURI.host);
    var regexp = new RegExp('google\.'+suffix,'i');
    if (regexp.test(httpChannel.originalURI.host)) {
            Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
            httpChannel.redirectTo(Services.io.newURI("http://test.tld", null, null));
        }


     }



  get observerService() {
    return Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
  },

  register: function()
  {
    this.observerService.addObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request", false);
  },

  unregister: function()
  {
    this.observerService.removeObserver(this, "http-on-modify-request");
  }
};

httpRequestObserver.register();
```

I'm trying to do a little POC, but it seems to load indefinitely.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't test the `originalURI`! It will stay [the same even after a redirect](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/54e78e0153a8/netwerk/base/public/nsIChannel.idl#l31)

```
/**
 * The original URI used to construct the channel. This is used in
 * the case of a redirect or URI "resolution" (e.g. resolving a
 * resource: URI to a file: URI) so that the original pre-redirect
 * URI can still be obtained. ...
 */
```

So you redirect, that creates a new channel with the **same** `originalURI` but different `URI`, so your test triggers again and again and again... causing the infinite redirection loop (and redirecting by this API also is not subject to the usual redirection limit).

Instead test the `.URI` of a channel, which gives the *current* URI.

Comment: No way i tried to answer to this question over addon forums and couldnt, nice catch!